# How to scrape multiple web-pages that will translate them from English to Hindi using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-translation-api

I am struggling with the small issue, the code works and no errors. But I need to figure out how to translate multiple pages from the website. From English to Hindi and each pages has to be Hindi, so far I only translated one specific text from the main website.

```py
#Script scraps the website using request and beautifulSoup library

from google_translate import browser
from google_translate import selenium
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://www.classcentral.com/?"
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"}
# Here the user agent is for Edge browser on windows 10. You can find your browser user agent from the above given link.
r = requests.get(url=URL, headers=headers)
print(r.content)
# Parsing the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
# find all the anchor tags with "href"
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

```py
#Script transalate text into Hindi using google translate API

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium
# Give Language code in which you want to translate the text:=>
lang_code = 'hi '

# Provide text that you want to translate:=>
input1 = " Find your next course.Class Central aggregates courses from many providers to help you find the best courses on almost any subject, wherever they exist"

# launch browser with selenium:=>
browser = webdriver.Chrome() #browser = webdriver.Chrome('path of chromedriver.exe file') if the chromedriver.exe is in different folder

# copy google Translator link here:=>
browser.get("https://translate.google.co.in/?sl=auto&tl="+lang_code+"&text="+input1+"&op=translate")

# just wait for some time for translating input text:=>
time.sleep(6)

# Given below x path contains the translated output that we are storing in output variable:=>
output1 = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'HwtZe').text

# Display the output:=>
print("Translated Paragraph:=> " + output1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google translate has some limitations. Based on my understanding you can’t translate all the characters in a single request. So I recommend you to translate the text in multiple requests.

In the below code, I am using the `googletrans` module and after fetching text from the website I am translating them into Hindi. As an alternative you can try below code,I hope this will helpful for you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

def scrape_web_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.get_text()
    return text

def language_translator(url):
    count=1
    for url in urls:
        newtest=""
        newtest=str(f"From page {count}")
        print(f'.........................from page {count} ...........................................')
        text = scrape_web_page(url)
        k=text.split()
        for i in k:
            #print(i)
            translated_text = translator.translate(i, dest='hi')
            newtest=newtest+" "+str(translated_text.text)
            #print(translated_text.text)
        count=count+1
        print(newtest)



urls = [
    'https://demo1/page1','https://demo1/page2'
    
]

language_translator(urls)
```

NB: There are some copyright issues involved in website scraping.